# how to parse diffrent array of dictionary in every uicollectionviewcell.?

Tags: ios

> I have a api please look at this first.

```
{"result":"Successful","data":[{"price":"100.00","packs":"Garbage Bags","pack_id":"1","products":[{"quantity":"15","image":"1454651885ECOWGBS_03.jpg"},{"quantity":"15","image":"1454652017ECOWGBM_03.jpg"},{"quantity":"15","image":"1454652132ECOWGBL_02.jpg"}]},{"price":"200.00","packs":"Party","pack_id":"2","products":[{"quantity":"50","image":"1454589144USI_6819.jpg"},{"quantity":"50","image":"1454587252ecow240b_01.jpg"},{"quantity":"50","image":"1454499020ecow10rp_01.jpg"}]},{"price":"300.00","packs":"Travel","pack_id":"3","products":[{"quantity":"25","image":"1454589144USI_6819.jpg"},{"quantity":"25","image":"1454588615ecow103crp_01.jpg"},{"quantity":"25","image":"1455532004ECOWCLAM1_03.jpg"}]},{"price":"400.00","packs":"Kids","pack_id":"4","products":[{"quantity":"25","image":"1454499251ecow6rp_01.jpg"},{"quantity":"25","image":"1454588417ecow5ct_01.jpg"},{"quantity":"25","image":"1454587802ecow340b_01.jpg"}]}]}
```

> Number of cell is generated demand upon the number of packs in api. For example in this api four pack are there so i parse the total number of pack and add it to array and than add that array in uicollectionview like this.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [packdetail count];
```

}

> Till now all thing working fine but when i tried to pass quantity in products data on uilabel it display on every cell and for only first products array. but i need to pass first products array on first cell and second product array on second cell and so on. Here is my code please look at this.

```
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
     {
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible =    NO;
  NSArray *dataarray = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];



[packdetail removeAllObjects];


for (NSDictionary *tmp in dataarray)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"packs"] forKey:@"packs"];
    [temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"pack_id"] forKey:@"pack_id"];

    [packdetail addObject:temp];
    NSLog(@"packdetail %@", packdetail);


    productarray = [tmp objectForKey:@"products"];
    NSLog(@"products %@", productarray);

    for (NSDictionary *product in productarray) {

          NSMutableDictionary *temp2 =[NSMutableDictionary new];
         [temp2 setObject:[product objectForKey:@"quantity"]forKey:@"quantity"];



        [quantity addObject:temp2];

    }


}
if (packdetail)
{
    [_subscriptioncollectionview reloadData];
}
```

}

```
     - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [packdetail count];
     }

    -(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView  *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

SubscriptionCell *cell = (SubscriptionCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



cell.packname.text = [[packdetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"packs"];
cell.productname.text = [[quantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"quantity"];


return cell;

 }
```

Comment: i am not able to add screen shot in my question, don't know why

Comment: cell.packname.text = [[packdetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"packs"][indexpath.row];

Comment: you are in correct way, no need or two arrays , single array is enough

Comment: No need to use for loop , you can set your json directly @sandeeptomar
and you can also get the value in DidSelect method in this way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your answer is**

```
for (NSDictionary *tmp in dataarray)
{
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"packs"] forKey:@"packs"];
[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"pack_id"] forKey:@"pack_id"];

[packdetail addObject:temp];
NSLog(@"packdetail %@", packdetail);


productarray = [tmp objectForKey:@"products"];
NSLog(@"products %@", productarray);

for (NSDictionary *product in productarray) {

      NSMutableDictionary *temp2 =[NSMutableDictionary new];
     [temp2 setObject:[product objectForKey:@"quantity"]forKey:@"quantity"];



    [quantity addObject:temp2];

}
}
```

**Change to**

```
for (NSDictionary *tmp in dataarray)
{
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"packs"] forKey:@"packs"];
[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"pack_id"] forKey:@"pack_id"];
NSLog(@"packdetail %@", packdetail);

productarray = [tmp objectForKey:@"products"];
NSLog(@"products %@", productarray);

for (NSDictionary *product in productarray) {
     [temp setObject:[product objectForKey:@"quantity"]forKey:@"quantity"];
}
    [packdetail addObject:temp];
}
```

**Display in cell**

```
cell.label.text = [[packdetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"quantity"];;
```

Comment: @sandeeptomar -- you are doing well, thing simple you get answer in easily

Comment: can i ask you one more little bit query sir??

Comment: right now i have only three quantity and three image in product they can be increase or decrease, so i want to know how will i create uilabel according to data which is come from api?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *array = [JsonArray];
```

in CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.label.text = [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"products"][indexpath.row]valueForkey @"quantity"];
```