# How to load JSON URL responsedata to tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm learning iOS, I have a problem with adding JSON URL to tableView. How can I invoke to TableView? Now, only in console display me JSON URL. Please help me. 
I don't know where can i have mistake.

```
//  WordsViewController.m


#import "WordsViewController.h"
#import "Word.h"


@interface WordsViewController ()

@end

@implementation WordsViewController
@synthesize jsonArray, wordsArray;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //set the title of our VC
    self.title = @"SŁOWNIK";

    //LOAD DATA
    [self simpleJsonParsing];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)simpleJsonParsing {
    //-- Make URL request with server
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://uidictionary.herokuapp.com/phrases.json"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //-- Get request and response though URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&amp;amp;amp;amp;response error:nil];

    //-- JSON Parsing
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSLog(@"Result = %@",result);
}

@end
```

Console show me:

```
2016-02-18 13:01:42.645 Słownik[20421:5341020] Result = {
    phrases =     (
        {
            expression = pejoratywny;
            meaning = "\U201eCo\U015b, co jest pejoratywne, wyra\U017ca czyj\U0105\U015b negatywn\U0105 ocen\U0119 lub, rzadziej, samo jest przedmiotem takiej oceny\U201d.\U00a0Inny s\U0142ownik j\U0119zyka polskiego\U00a0PWN, z kt\U00f3rego przytoczy\U0142em t\U0119 definicj\U0119, podaje gar\U015b\U0107 cytat\U00f3w, w nich za\U015b znajdziemy takie po\U0142\U0105czenia wyrazowe, jak\U00a0znaczenie pejoratywne,okre\U015blenie pejoratywne,\U00a0cechy pejoratywne. Jak st\U0105d wynika, przymiotnik ten ma do\U015b\U0107 szeroki zakres u\U017cycia. \U0141\U0105cz\U0105c go ze s\U0142owem\U00a0zabarwienie, nie dublujemy jego tre\U015bci.";
        },
        {
            expression = "Ruby on Rails";
            meaning = "\U00a0(cz\U0119sto nazywany\U00a0RoR\U00a0lub po prostu\U00a0Rails) \U2013\U00a0framework\U00a0open source\U00a0do szybkiego tworzenia\U00a0aplikacji webowych\U00a0stworzony g\U0142\U00f3wnie przez du\U0144skiego programist\U0119\U00a0Davida Heinemeiera Hanssona\U00a0w ramach pracy nad oprogramowaniem\U00a0Basecamp. RoR zosta\U0142 napisany w j\U0119zyku\U00a0Ruby\U00a0z u\U017cyciem architektury\U00a0MVC\U00a0(ang.\U00a0Model-View-Controller).";
        },
    );
}
```

Comment: you are in the corret way

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, but I don't know what next. Could you resolve my problem bro ? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

create the one NSMutableArray iyour viewdidLoad

```
@interface WordsViewController ()
{
 NSMutableArray *finalResultArray;
 }
 @end


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
//set the title of our VC
self.title = @"SŁOWNIK";

 finalResultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
//LOAD DATA
[self simpleJsonParsing];
```

}

```
//-- JSON Parsing
NSArray *result = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]objectForKey:@"phrases"];

  [finalResultArray removeAllobjects];
NSLog(@"Result = %@",result);
 for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in result)
{


NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"expression"] forKey:@"expression"];
[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"meaning"] forKey:@"meaning"];

[finalResultArray addObject:temp];
 }

if (finalResultArray)
{
[self.tableView reloadData];
}


  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return finalResultArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.textlabel.text = [[finalResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"expression"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I dont have a time , i am leaving from office now, it works,

Comment: see this once it also helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478162/how-to-parse-diffrent-array-of-dictionary-in-every-uicollectionviewcell/35478554#35478554

Comment: U need any help ask me i wait for your response

Comment: I cant help u at the moment, i go to my hme comeing monday only i reach office i tell the concept u can do Simple create one label or use tableview detailtextlabel text ( cell.detailtextlabel.text = [[ finalarray objectatIndex: indexpath.row]objectForKey:@"meaning"];

Comment: Change your tableview style as UITableviewcellstylesubtitle, after that the above line is work, congrats do well

Comment: thanks a lot for help! now I try add details to label in DetailsViewController.

Comment: @Mike91 --  I am back, your problem is resolved or not

Comment: sure , can you give the upvote for this , it is useful for others